# VBA to autofit and then add white space before filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I have a command button which is filtering some data and then creating a PDF to print. I currently have the page set to autofit the row height but the text feels too cramped, I was hoping to find a way to autofit and then either add padding or double the height so that it looks cleaner. So far everything I tried/found would only change the height of one row at a time.

I was trying to do something like this:

```
Rows("1:100").AutoFit
Rows("1:100").RowHeight = Rows("1:100").RowHeight * 2
```

Also, I am very much a beginner at this and just learning by reading through forums so sorry if my explanations aren't adequate.

This is what I currently have going on with my command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("PRINT OUT").Visible = True


Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="YES"

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False

End With
[a1:x99].ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Sheets("PRINT OUT").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I do not get your question as you start telling it feels cramped, you show us some code but in your code for the button this is not shown? Maybe an idea to show some screenshots? And tell us what "cramped" means

Answer (score 0):

If you have rows that have the same height, you could say something like

debug.print Selection.RowHeight

and it will tell you the rowHeight, but if any of the rows have different heights, that same code will return null.  So your code isn't working because it's trying to multiply by null.

The only way to do what your asking is row by row, but that's not hard to do in VBA, it would just be something like

```
Sub ScaleRowHeight(vRange as range, vMultScale as double, vAddScale as double)
    dim i as long
    for i = 1 to vrange.rows.count
        vRange.rows(i).rowHeight = vRange.rows(i).rowHeight * vMultScale + vAddScale
    next i
End Sub
```

And then you'd just call it in your code by saying

```
Rows("1:100").AutoFit
call ScaleRowHeight(rows("1:100"),2,0)
```

but really you wouldn't want to make your tall blocks twice as tall, you'd probably want to just add a fixed amount to all of them

```
Rows("1:100").AutoFit
call ScaleRowHeight(rows("1:100"),1,10)
```

Cheers!